# How to make a Jenkins/Hudson job surveil some others jobs and decide whether to build or not?

Tags: groovy, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

**PROBLEM**

Given that all the jobs have string `LEVEL_X` in it's job name, where X is a number > 1. I want every job with X = n to surveil every job with `X = n-1`, and start building if each of them is finished with success. And I want the job with `X = n` to surveil the other jobs with an interval of 1 minute.

First of all, I am interested in knowing what the best way is to do that, second I want the solution if one can be implemented by a small script, maybe a groovy script which can be run in `system groovy script` using the GROOVY PLUGIN.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here are some hints and code snippets:

- There is a Groovy Script console at `http://<jenkins-server>/script` that will help you with debugging your scripts.
- Here is a link to [Jenkins Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).
- Code snippet that outputs all job names:

  ```
  def hi = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
     hi.getItems(hudson.model.Project).each {project ->
     println(project.displayName)
  }
  ```
- Code snippet that extracts `n` from `LEVEL_n` (implemented as closure):

  ```
  def level = { name ->
    def ret = 0
    name.eachMatch(~'LEVEL_([1-9]+[0-9*])', {ret = it[1].toInteger()})
    return ret
  }
  ```
- Code snippet that gets statuses for all the latest builds:

  ```
  def hi = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
  hi.getItems(hudson.model.Project).each {project ->
    println(project.lastBuild.result)
  }
  ```
- Link to the method that [starts a build](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#scheduleBuild%28int,%20hudson.model.Cause).

Note: things get a bit hairier if you are using Matrix builds. But as long as you don't this should be enough.

Comment: +1 for the jenkins server script url - the node groovy console is worthless, since it doesn't import all the classes.

Comment: In the groovy console I'm finding the full script/command has to be all on one line, otherwise various syntax errors. e.g. the job name snippet works for me like this: '''def hi = hudson.model.Hudson.instance; hi.getItems(hudson.model.Project).each {project -> println(project.displayName) }'''

Comment: just a FYI for folks; some of these API methods have to be given scriptApproval to run in a job.