# How to retrieve Jenkins build parameters using the Groovy API?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have a parameterized job that uses the Perforce plugin and would like to retrieve the build parameters/properties as well as the p4.change property that's set by the Perforce plugin.

How do I retrieve these properties with the Jenkins Groovy API?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Regarding parameters:

[See this answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781891/1178189). To get a list of all the builds for a project (obtained as per that answer):

```
project.builds
```

When you find your particular build, you need to get all actions of type [ParametersAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParametersAction.html) with [`build.getActions(hudson.model.ParametersAction)`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Actionable.html#getActions()). You then query the returned object for your specific parameters.

Regarding p4.change: I suspect that it is also stored as an action. In Jenkins Groovy console get all actions for a build that contains p4.change and examine them - it will give you an idea what to look for in your code.

Answer (score 35):

**Update: Jenkins 2.x solution:**

With Jenkins 2 pipeline dsl, you can directly access any parameter with the trivial syntax based on the `params` (Map) built-in:

`echo " FOOBAR value: ${params.'FOOBAR'}"`

The returned value will be a String or a boolean depending on the Parameter type itself. The syntax is the same for scripted or declarative syntax. More info at: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-parameters

If your parameter name is itself in a variable:

```
def paramName = "FOOBAR"
def paramValue = params.get(paramName) // or: params."${paramName}"
echo """ FOOBAR value: ${paramValue}"
```

**Original Answer for Jenkins 1.x:**

For Jenkins 1.x, the syntax is based on the `build.buildVariableResolver` built-ins:

```
// ... or if you want the parameter by name ...
def hardcoded_param = "FOOBAR"
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
def hardcoded_param_value = resolver.resolve(hardcoded_param)
```

Please note the official Jenkins Wiki page covers this in more details as well, especially how to iterate upon the build parameters:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+System+Groovy+script

The salient part is reproduced below:

```
// get parameters
def parameters = build?.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters
parameters.each {
   println "parameter ${it.name}:"
   println it.dump()
}
```

Comment: This is failing with "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: WorkflowScript" Any idea?. Most probably build parameter is not accessible while running parameterized jenkins job with groovy pipeline.

Comment: This (old) answer applies for a Jenkins 1.x service, while you've likely tried it in a Jenkins 2.x env, via a Jenkinsfile ?

Comment: I am trying to access in a groovy pipeline. But i found the solution (thanks to the clue in your answer). there is a "params" global that i used to retrieve build parameter map.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am too kind of stuck here."groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: WorkflowScript"

Comment: Again, I'm pretty sure this only works with the old Jenkins 1.x with the Parameterized Groovy Script plugin, but not with Jenkins 2.x. For the latter, you can replace the whole script with: `def value = params.'FOOBAR'` . It is essentially directly supported by the pipeline groovy syntax.

Answer (score 27):

For resolving a single parameter (I guess what's most commonly needed), this is the simplest I found:

> build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("myparameter")

in your Groovy System script build step.

Comment: This results in `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: Script1`

Comment: @dokaspar  Because this work for groovy script plugin

Comment: if your groovy is a class, how do you do this?

Answer (score 10):

I've just got this working, so specifically, using the Groovy Postbuild plugin, you can do the following:

```
def paramText
def actionList = manager.build.getActions(hudson.model.ParametersAction)
if (actionList.size() != 0)
{
  def pA = actionList.get(0)
  paramText = pA.createVariableResolver(manager.build).resolve("MY_PARAM_NAME")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In cases when a parameter name cannot be hardcoded I found this would be the simplest and best way to access parameters:

```
def myParam = env.getProperty(dynamicParamName)
```

In cases, when a parameter name is known and can be hardcoded the following 3 lines are equivalent:

```
def myParam = env.getProperty("myParamName")
def myParam = env.myParamName
def myParam = myParamName
```

Comment: I was looking for getting a dynamic param, env.getProperty worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To get the parameterized build params from the current build from your GroovyScript (using Pipeline), all you need to do is:
Say you had a variable called VARNAME.

`def myVariable = env.VARNAME`

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get all parameters passed to Jenkins job you can use the global variable **params** in your groovy pipeline to fetch it.

> http://jenkins_host:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals
>
> **params**

Use something like below.

```
def dumpParameter()
{
  params.each {
    println it.key + " = " + it.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Get all of the parameters:

```
System.getenv().each{
  println it
}
```

Or more sophisticated:

```
def myvariables = getBinding().getVariables()
for (v in myvariables) {
   echo "${v} " + myvariables.get(v)
}
```

You will need to **disable** "Use Groovy Sandbox" for both.

Comment: the later one doesn't work for me, I am getting an empty array

Comment: Do you know how I may set it though? I can write up a new question for you to answer

Answer (score 2):

thanks [patrice-n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366749/patrice-m)! this code worked to get both queued and running jobs and their parameters:

```
import hudson.model.Job
import hudson.model.ParametersAction
import hudson.model.Queue
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

println("================================================")
for (Job job : Jenkins.instanceOrNull.getAllItems(Job.class)) {
    if (job.isInQueue()) {
        println("------------------------------------------------")
        println("InQueue " + job.name)

        Queue.Item queue = job.getQueueItem()
        if (queue != null) {
            println(queue.params)
        }
    }
    if (job.isBuilding()) {
        println("------------------------------------------------")
        println("Building " + job.name)

        def build = job.getBuilds().getLastBuild()
        def parameters = build?.getAllActions().find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters
        parameters.each {
            def dump = it.dump()
            println "parameter ${it.name}: ${dump}"
        }
    }
}
println("================================================")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet worked for me to get a parameter value in a parameterized project:
`String myParameter = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('MY_PARAMETER')`

The goal was to dynamically lock a resource based on the selected project parameter.

In "[✓] This build requires lockable resources" I have the following "[✓] Groovy Expression":

```
if (resourceName == 'resource_lock_name') {
    Binding binding = this.getProperty('binding')
    String profile = binding.getVariable('BUILD_PROFILE')

    return profile == '-Poradb' // acquire lock if "oradb" profile is selected
}

return false
```

In "[✓] This project is parameterized" section I have a "Choice Parameter" named e.g. *BUILD_PROFILE*
Example of Choices are:

```
-Poradb
-Ph2db
-DskipTests -T4
```

The lock on "resource_lock_name" will be acquired only if "-Poradb" is selected when building project with parameters

[-] Use Groovy Sandbox shall be unchecked for this syntax to work

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to retreive an environment parameter:

```
println System.getenv("MY_PARAM")
```

Comment: IIRC, the Groovy script is run on the master, not the slave. Things may have changed since I asked the original question, though.