# How to get job parameter by Groovy Script in post build

Tags: groovy, jenkins

My project is a work-flow control system, and the Jenkins is responsible for build phase.
After building successfully, Jenkins would trigger another servlet to do following work and pass a job parameter(processSN) to the servlet.

I set a parameter(processSN) as I trigger this job by its token.
And hope to pass the parameter to servlet as building successfully.

The example I find, always show the "default" parameter but what I expect is the input parameter as I trigger the job
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+job+parameters

**How could I get the input parameter(processSN) by groovy script in post build phase ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882515/how-to-retrieve-jenkins-build-parameters-using-the-groovy-api

Comment: Thanks @Jayan . I read that before, but can't understand how to implement... . Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us know what you don't understand. I would suggest following the link of the accepted answer and make yourself familiar with the Jenkins API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs for the Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin#GroovyPostbuildPlugin-Example2) you should use:

```
manager.build.buildVariables.get("processSN")
```