# How to call Jenkins parameter inside a groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, devops

Can any one tell me how to call jenkin parameter value into the groovy script?

Im creating a jenkins job that give permission to a another job for a perticular User.

below pic shows the parameter. i want to call that parameter value into the groovy script

[image: screenshot]

please find the script below:

```
import hudson.model.AbstractProject
import hudson.model.Item
import hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty
import hudson.security.Permission

AbstractProject proj = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("testjob")
AuthorizationMatrixProperty authProperty = proj.getProperty(AuthorizationMatrixProperty.class)
Set<String> users = new HashSet<>();
users.add('userid'); // XXX
Map<Permission,Set<String>> newPermissions = new HashMap<Permission, Set<String>>()
newPermissions.put(Item.READ, users)

proj.addProperty(new AuthorizationMatrixProperty(newPermissions))
proj.save()
```

That parameter value should have to come here `userid` in the groovy script

can any one tell me how to call jenkin parameter value into the groovy script

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve Jenkins build parameters using the Groovy API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882515/how-to-retrieve-jenkins-build-parameters-using-the-groovy-api)

Comment: can any one help me out clearly.how to call the string parameter value into script.some one reply me.its bit urgent

Comment: see the answer by 'inger' in the thread mentioned as duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23665470/12704

Comment: i did not understand where to keep that line in my code

Comment: i tried but no user please help me out fast

Comment: some one reply me fast

Answer (score 0):

I think the asnwer your`e looking for is this:
string(name: 'UserID', defaultValue: '',description: 'Enter ID here')