# jenkins script console: list of available jenkins methods?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I would like to use the jenkins script console some more.

Where do I have to look in order to find a list of available Objects/Methods that I can use via groovy? Is there something online? Should I browse the source on Github? Where would I start?

Like in this example, how would I have known that `hudson.model.Hudson.instance.pluginManager.plugins` exists and is ready to be called from the jenkins script console?

```
println(hudson.model.Hudson.instance.pluginManager.plugins)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for [Jenkins Main Module API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781891/1178189) helpful in getting yourself on your way.

Answer (score 3):

You can enter a [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) script in the script console.

The complete API can be found at the [jenkins javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Jenkins' script console validates, but isn't an IDE or editor of much utility on its own... :(

Comment: the link on groovy to the codehaus servers is dead sind 2015. the project has moved.