# Jenkins labels - always use one node, but use others if not available

Tags: jenkins

We have one particular build machine that we would like a Jenkins job to always use.

However, if this machine is not available for some reason, we would like it to use a backup machine/s.

I presumed that using the 'or' syntax in the label would achieve that goal, but it seems this is not what it was intended for.

For example, I have a machine called 'windows-01'. This is the machine I always want the job to run against unless it's offline. If offline, I'd like it to use the label 'BACKUP_MACHINES'. I was hoping I could do something like:

`windows-01||BACKUP_MACHINES`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, it will still randomly select a machine. Does anyone aware of solutions or know of plugins for such a scenario?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900538/can-jenkins-nodes-be-given-priority-for-build-jobs

Answer (score 1):

Use [priority sorter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin) or similar alternatives (e.g. [Scoring Load Banancer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scoring+Load+Balancer+plugin)).