# Jenkins Load Balancing - Automatic routing on other free system

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, load-balancing

Now I would like to describe the following problem on my part here.

We have several test systems that previously had the problem that start the Jenkins Jobs simultaneously. I would like to avoid this by providing some kind of recognition. It's about distributing the started Jenkins jobs on our test machines.

Example:

Test 1 runs at the customer - Test 2 should recognize this

For example, if test-1 is occupied by Job1, it should be recognized at the start of Job 2 and then automatically routed to one of the free test machines.

Comment: Try to use least load plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload and check this thread as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024007/how-can-i-modify-the-load-balancing-behavior-jenkins-uses-to-control-slaves

Answer (score 2):

Manage Jenkins> Manage Nodes > Node > Configure

You must set same label names for different nodes.

Restrict where this project can be run = new label name

(You must install 'Least Load plugin')