# Jenkins: How to choose an agent under a same label

Tags: jenkins

Assume that Jenkins has three agents (**Agent_1,Agent_2,Agent_3**) 
Both of them are labeled **Linux_Server**

**`Question:`**
When I select Linux_server to run a job, by default which agent will Jenkins
choose to actually run the job for me?
Jenkins will do it totally randomly ? Or choose a different agent ? Or choose a agent with least number of job? Or anything else ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what their [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Schedulingstrategy) says:

> Some agents are faster, while others are slow. Some agents are closer
>   (network wise) to a master, others are far away. So doing a good build
>   distribution is a challenge. Currently, Jenkins employs the following
>   strategy:
>
> 1. If a project is configured to stick to one computer, that's always
>      honored.
> 2. Jenkins tries to build a project on the same computer that
>      it was previously built.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024007/how-can-i-modify-the-load-balancing-behavior-jenkins-uses-to-control-slaves) for a few more sophisticated approaches. Especially the [Least Load Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Least+Load+Plugin) might sound interesting.