# Jenkins Workflow API - stage status

Tags: jenkins-workflow

What information are we able to query on a workflow job? Anything regarding a particular build's stage status (succeeded, failed, hasn't reached yet, aborted, etc.)? I see we can interact with the `input` step using [this method](http://udaypal.com/workflow-integration-using-rest-api/), but where can we find what metadata, if anything, can be obtained about our builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST exported API for builds (`…/job/…/…/api/json?tree=…`) is not very extensive yet. You can get some information about nodes in the flow graph (steps, and some associated block nodes—the stuff you see in *Workflow Steps*). It is possible to extract some information about stages from that, albeit not easily. Much more is available from the Java API.

Comment: Did some searching and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777663/how-to-make-a-jenkins-hudson-job-surveil-some-others-jobs-and-decide-whether-to/10781891#10781891) was helpful in getting me started. Looking through the [Job](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html) class, I don't see anything related to stages or workflow. Any pointers you can offer on querying workflow-specific job info?